# Mirror diagonaly in sculpting mode

Tags: sculpting, mirror

Im new to blender, and have a question regarding sculpting.

I want tu mirror my sculpting by the x and y axis, but only diagonaly (as in photo).

Right now I can only achieve this with the effect sculpted also both by the x and the y separetly.

Do anybody know how to achive the outcome I want?

[image: screenshot]